# Writable instance is reused in hadoop in same reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am observing an unexpected behavior in which I am seeing the custom `writable` created by reducer getting reused in the same reducer.

For example

```
public class myWritable implements Writable {

    private Map<Long, MyObject> myObjectMap = new HashMap<>();
    private myInt;

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeInt(myInt);
        out.writeInt(myObjectMap.size());
        for (MyObject myObjectInstance: myObjectMap.values()) {
            out.writeLong(myObjectInstance.getId());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        myInt = in.readInt();
        int myObjectMapSize = in.readInt();

        int myObjectId;

        for (int i = 0; i < myObjectMapSize; i++) {
            myObjectId = in.readLong();

            myObjectMap.put(myObjectId, new MyObject(myObjectId));
        }
    }
}
```

I find that `myObjectMap` just keep increase in size for subsequent keys that I processed. This means that each reducer is reusing the writable instance that was created.

This doesn't quite make sense to me since I am not seeing this behavior documented in the [doc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable.html)

Am I doing anything wrong?